# Azure DevOps, central (secure) pipeline for code signing in separate project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have a number of Repos in several Projects, all in the same Organization, that must go through the same code-signing process.  Each project is built in its own way.

From the point of view of the various project owners (e.g. Project A), I would like the experience to be:

Project A gets built -> Project A sends its unsigned package to a Central pipeline -> "stuff happens" -> Project A gets a signed package back from Central pipeline and does whatever it wants to do

"stuff happens" means: The Central pipeline will do the work of downloading the unsigned package from the calling pipeline, getting code signing certificates from an *Azure key vault*, doing the signing, and publishing back the signed package to the pipeline so the calling pipeline can retrieve it, and do whatever it wants to do with it (presumably, publish it somewhere).

Here is how I would like to do the code signing:

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Install NuGetKeyVaultSignTool
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        custom: 'tool'
        arguments: 'install --tool-path . NuGetKeyVaultSignTool'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Running NuGetKeyVaultSign
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          .\NuGetKeyVaultSignTool sign $(unsignedNupkgFilename) `
          --file-digest "sha256" `
          --timestamp-rfc3161 "http://timestamp.digicert.com" `
          --timestamp-digest "sha256" `
          --azure-key-vault-url "$(azure-key-vault-url)" `
          --azure-key-vault-tenant-id "$(azure-key-vault-tenant-id)" `
          --azure-key-vault-client-id "$(azure-key-vault-client-id)" `
          --azure-key-vault-client-secret "$(azure-key-vault-client-secret)" `
          --azure-key-vault-certificate "CodeSigningCertificate"
```

All those $(azure-*) variables should be stored as a *variable group* in a *Library*, and I don't want every project having access to them.  They are used to get "CodeSigningCertificate" from $(azure-key-vault-url), and produce a signed version of $(unsignedNupkgFilename).  This would be published back onto the pipeline so Project A could take it from there.

Making this a template that Project A can call doesn't seem to work.  Those $(azure-*) variables are assumed to be defined in Project A's Library, not Central's Library.  So I'd have to give them out to the project owners.

I would like each team to be given a single line to drop into their existing yml's that does the code signing and spits out the result, without them knowing or caring about how the certificate signing is happening and any parameters it requires.